Earnings Data on Meta's new Content Monetization Not Working through Video_Insights
Since Meta has moved pages from in-stream ads to Content Monetization, the video_insights / total_video_ad_break_earnings has stopped showing up.
It gives this error:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) Monetization metrics are only visible for Page admins with access to monetization insights.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "Ap-R3KlquI-LCVIDcC9dXqD"
}
}

We, and our clients, have the correct admin rights and were able to get earnings data before the update. The update is the only thing that has changed.
How do we update the code to make it work?
